# How to get event category on same date from custom calendar

Tags: java, android, sqlite, calendar

This is my calendar activity.inserted data from this activity...
second is my calendar adapter class when I get data from `sqlite` I want to find, on the same date how many events are present and which categories they belong.

```
 MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.
                    getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

            if (!prefs.contains("insertedInDB")) {
                // insert in DB
                // add events in database
                db.addEvent(new CalendarEvent("Birthday", "2015-11-15", "Location-House", "aa"));
          //event name,event date,event location,event category
                db.addEvent(new CalendarEvent("Birthday", "2015-11-15", "Location- House", "bb"));
                db.addEvent(new CalendarEvent("Mobile Computing Paper", "2015-11-01", "Location- college", "bb"));
                db.addEvent(new CalendarEvent("Birthday", "2015-11-01", "Location-House", "bb"));          
                db.addEvent(new CalendarEvent("31th December", "2015-11-30", "Party Location-House" , "cc"));


                // create key in prefs
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("insertedInDB", true);
                editor.commit();
            } else {
                // no need to insert in db
            }
```

**CalendarAdapter.java:**

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Locale;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
    import android.util.TypedValue;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;



    public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;

        private java.util.Calendar month;
        public GregorianCalendar pmonth;

        /*-----------calendar instance for previous month for getting complete view-------------------*/

        public GregorianCalendar pmonthmaxset;
        private GregorianCalendar selectedDate;
        int firstDay;
        int maxWeeknumber;
        int maxP;
        int calMaxP;
        int lastWeekDay;
        int leftDays;
        int mnthlength;
        BadgeView badge;
        String itemvalue, curentDateString;
        DateFormat df;
        LinearLayout event_dateview_layout;
        View first_event_date_view, second_event_date_view, third_event_date_view, fourth_event_date_view;
        private ArrayList<String> items;
        public static List<String> day_string;
        private View previousView;
        public ArrayList<CalendarEvent> event_calendar_arr;

        public CalendarAdapter(Context context, GregorianCalendar monthCalendar, ArrayList<CalendarEvent> event_calendar_arr) {

            this.event_calendar_arr = event_calendar_arr;
            CalendarAdapter.day_string = new ArrayList<String>();
            Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
            month = monthCalendar;
            selectedDate = (GregorianCalendar) monthCalendar.clone();
            this.context = context;
            month.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            this.items = new ArrayList<String>();
            df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
            curentDateString = df.format(selectedDate.getTime());
            refreshDays();

        }

        public void setItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
            for (int i = 0; i != items.size(); i++) {
                if (items.get(i).length() == 1) {
                    items.set(i, "0" + items.get(i));
                }
            }
            this.items = items;
        }

        public int getCount() {

            return day_string.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return day_string.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return 0;
        }

        // create a new view for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            TextView dayView;

            if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                // attributes
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.event_date_view, parent, false);
                event_dateview_layout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.event_dateview_layout);
                first_event_date_view = v.findViewById(R.id.first_event_date_view);
                second_event_date_view = v.findViewById(R.id.second_event_date_view);
                third_event_date_view = v.findViewById(R.id.third_event_date_view);
                fourth_event_date_view = v.findViewById(R.id.fourth_event_date_view);

            }
            dayView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_text);
            String[] separatedTime = day_string.get(position).split("-");

            String gridvalue = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*", "");
            if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) > 1) && (position < firstDay)) {
                dayView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                dayView.setClickable(false);
                dayView.setFocusable(false);
            } else if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) < 7) && (position > 28)) {
                dayView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                dayView.setClickable(false);
                dayView.setFocusable(false);
            } else {
                // setting curent month's days in blue color.
                dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }


            if (day_string.get(position).equals(curentDateString)) {

                event_dateview_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            } else {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#343434"));
            }


            dayView.setText(gridvalue);

            // create date string for comparison
            String date = day_string.get(position);

            if (date.length() == 1) {
                date = "0" + date;
            }
            String monthStr = "" + (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
            if (monthStr.length() == 1) {
                monthStr = "0" + monthStr;
            }

            // show icon if date is not empty and it exists in the items array
            /*ImageView iw = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_icon);
            if (date.length() > 0 && items != null && items.contains(date)) {
                iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                iw.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            */

            setEventView(v, position, dayView);

            return v;
        }

        public View setSelected(View view, int pos) {
            if (previousView != null) {
                previousView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#343434"));
            }

            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);


            int len = day_string.size();
            if (len > pos) {
                if (day_string.get(pos).equals(curentDateString)) {

                } else {

                    previousView = view;

                }

            }


            return view;
        }

        public void refreshDays() {
            // clear items
            items.clear();
            day_string.clear();
            Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
            pmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();
            // month start day. ie; sun, mon, etc
            firstDay = month.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            // finding number of weeks in current month.
            maxWeeknumber = month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
            // allocating maximum row number for the gridview.
            mnthlength = maxWeeknumber * 7;
            maxP = getMaxP(); // previous month maximum day 31,30....
            calMaxP = maxP - (firstDay - 1);// calendar offday starting 24,25 ...
            /**
             * Calendar instance for getting a complete gridview including the three
             * month's (previous,current,next) dates.
             */
            pmonthmaxset = (GregorianCalendar) pmonth.clone();
            /**
             * setting the start date as previous month's required date.
             */
            pmonthmaxset.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calMaxP + 1);

            /**
             * filling calendar gridview.
             */
            for (int n = 0; n < mnthlength; n++) {

                itemvalue = df.format(pmonthmaxset.getTime());
                pmonthmaxset.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
                day_string.add(itemvalue);

            }
        }

        private int getMaxP() {
            int maxP;
            if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
                    .getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
                pmonth.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                        month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
            } else {
                pmonth.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                        month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
            }
            maxP = pmonth.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            return maxP;
        }

        public void setEventView(View v, int pos, TextView txt) {

            //get array size in len
            int len = CalendarEvent.event_calendar_arr.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                CalendarEvent cal_obj = CalendarEvent.event_calendar_arr.get(i);
                //get event date
                String category = cal_obj.getEventCate();
                String date = cal_obj.getEventDate();

                int len1 = day_string.size();
                if (len1 > pos) {

                    if (day_string.get(pos).equals(date)) {

                        if ("aa".equals(category)) {
                            event_dateview_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                        } else if ("bb".equals(category)) {
                            event_dateview_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        } else if ("cc".equals(category)) {
                            event_dateview_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        } else if ("dd".equals(category)) {
                            event_dateview_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        } else if ("aa,bb".equals(category)) {
                            first_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                            second_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                            third_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            fourth_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        } else if ("bb,cc".equals(category)) {
                            first_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            second_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            third_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            fourth_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        } else if ("cc,dd".equals(category)) {
                            first_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            second_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            third_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                            fourth_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        } else if ("aa,bb,cc".equals(category)) {
                            first_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                            second_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            third_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            fourth_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        } else if ("bb,cc,dd".equals(category)) {
                            first_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                            second_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            third_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            fourth_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        } else if ("aa,bb,cc,dd".equals(category)) {
                            first_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                            second_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            third_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            fourth_event_date_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        }

                        txt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    }
                }
            }


        }

        public void getPositionList(String date, final Activity act) {

            String event_date = null;
            String event_name = null;
            String event_desc = null;
            int len = 0;
            len = CalendarEvent.event_calendar_arr.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                CalendarEvent cal_event = CalendarEvent.event_calendar_arr.get(i);

                event_date = cal_event.getEventDate();
                event_name = cal_event.getEventName();
                event_desc = cal_event.getEventDesc();


                if (date.equals(event_date)) {

                    Intent in = new Intent(context, Event.class);
                    in.putExtra("EVENT_DATE", event_date);
                    in.putExtra("EVENT_NAME", event_name);
                    in.putExtra("EVENT_DESC", event_desc);
                    context.startActivity(in);


    //                Toast.makeText(context, "You have event on this date: " + event_date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    //                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    //                        .setTitle("Date: " + event_date)
    //                        .setMessage("Event: " + event_message)
    //                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    //                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    //                                act.finish();
    //                            }
    //                        }).show();
    //                break;
                }
            }
        }


    }
```